# Type hint a Python dictionary having integers as keys

Tags: python, python-typing

Suppose I have a function that returns a dictionary having integers as keys and instances of a defined custom class as values:

```
from typing import Dict

class A:
  a = 4

def my_f() -> dict:
  return {0: A()}
```

I want to type hint the type of keys and values. Many posts suggest to use `TypedDict` but this is not possible when using integers as keys.

How can I type hint a dictionary with integers as keys?

Comment: `dict[int, A]`, perhaps? `TypedDict` is for when you have a certain _set_ of keys. If you mean you want receivers to know it _only_ has `0` as a key, you'd have to use the non-class form - `TypedDict('MyDict', {0: A})`.

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for `MyDict = TypedDict('MyDict', {0: A})`

Comment: Also, `TypedDict` is for when your dict stores various *types* of values, rather than a single value type. The restriction to `str`-valued keys seems like it is imposed more by the syntax than anything else. (That is, I'm not sure what else prevents something like `TypedDict('D', {1: str, '2': bool})` from working.)

Comment: The example given is too minimal. For instance `dict[Literal[0], A | Exception]` typechecks just fine for the given example but that is obviously not the intent. We can't suggest a type hint here if you don't put into words what types you want to allow for the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
from typing import Dict

class A:
  a = 4

def my_f() -> dict:
  return {0: A()}
```

The from typing should be removed, the reason is twofold.  First Dict is unused in your code.  Second, for convenience you can just use the lowercase form.  To type hint my_f use the below.  Because dict was made multifunctional in that it could both be used to create a new object or be used as a type, Dict has been depreciated.

```
def my_f() -> dict[int, A]:
    return {0: A()}
```

Giving you

```
Class A:
    a = 4

def my_f() -> dict[int, A]:
    return {0: A()}
```

For more information, read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Comment: The real reason to use `dict` is that `typing.Dict` is deprecated; it was introduced before `dict` was made generic.

Comment: Wasn't aware it was depreciated, but yeah I remember.

Comment: There is a case for using typing.Dict if you are aiming for more compatibility, but honestly probably should just update thinking about it.

Comment: That's an ever-dwindling use case, though. The last version that *doesn't* support generic `dict` reaches end-of-life in about 8 months. The conversion from Python 2 to Python 3 had the side effect of making people think you need to support really old versions of Python, but it is *far* easier to upgrade from one 3.x to another than it ever was to upgrade from Python 2.x to Python 3.x. (Modern tooling helps; the path from 3.x to 3.y is also simpler than 2.x to 2.y was 15-20 years ago.)